# WPF: grouping "live" data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collectionview

### Model:

Let's assume that I have the `Book` model.

```
public class Book
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public DateTime Published { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I have such a DataService. It has the events to keep the books up to date on the client side:

```
public interface IBookService
{
    List<Book> GetAllBooks();

    // Book changed event.
    EventHandler<BookChangedEventArgs> BookChanged;

    // Book added/removed event.
    EventHandler<BooksCollectionChangedEventArgs> BooksCollectionChanged;
}
```

### WPF (MVVM) UI Client:

I have `BookViewModel` class (wraps `Book`).
I have an `ObservableCollection<BookViewModel>` which is synchronized with some implementation of `IBookService` interface.

So, the question. It is necessary to allow user to **choose one of the book (not Genre and not Author)** with the following UI:

[image: The UI]

Flat collection of `BookViewModel` should be somehow "grouped" sequentially (or I don't how to call it right):

1. Genres.
2. Authors (of selected genre).
3. Books (of selected genre and selected author).

So, the each level is a **master** for its descendant level.

Also, you might mention the Previous/Next buttons. They should navigate through **books level** (the last one):
For example, if **the last book** is selected and you press Next (see the image), the next state of the UI should be: Second genre => Second Author => Some book (of the second genre and second author).

How to achieve such a complex UI: multilevel grouping? What is the simplest way to implement such a book browser?
I would appreciate if you could provide me with some similar example.

Answer (score 1):

He Serge,

I would just use one SelectBookViewModel which implements your IBookService. This ViewModel holds a `Collection<Book>` or an `ObservableCollection<Book>`. Every time you get an UpdateEvent that updates your Book-Collection, then you perform an LINQ query on this collection to get a list of the genres like:

```cs
GenreListProperty = (from book in books
                     select book.Genre).Distinct().ToList();
```

Bind your first ListView to this `GenreListProperty`. Implemet some other logic to query lists for the other ListViews in th same style depending on Change-Events of the `SelectedItem` propery of the first list box.

The Buttons just do some navigation on the ListViews and their updating logic on `SelectedItem` changes. When pressing the Ok Button you just do a combined LINQ query on the Book-Collection to select the choosen one which your processing goes on with.